# I want to use metadata in my apex code to getting the value

Tags: apex, rest-api, metadata-api

I used a custom label to store my twilio accountSID and phone. But instead of that I want to use Custom metadata to store my accountSID and phone and use them in my code. How can I do it - plz help me in that! Here is my code:

```apex
    public class TwilioServices {
         @InvocableMethod(label='Send SMS' description='Send SMS' category='SMS' callout=true)
        public static List<TwilioServices.InputWrapper> run(List<InputWrapper> message){
            sendSMS(message.get(0));
            return message;
        }
    
    private static void sendSMS(InputWrapper input){

        HttpRequest httpReq = new HttpRequest();        
        httpReq.setEndpoint('callout:Twilio'+'/2010-04-01/Accounts/'+SYSTEM.LABEL.TWILIOACCOUNTSID+'/Messages.json');
        //httpReq.setHeader('Authorization', authoraizationHeader);
        httpReq.setMethod('POST');
        httpReq.setHeader('Content-Type', '"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"');
        String body = 'From='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(System.Label.TWILIO_PHONE, 'UTF-8')+'&Body='
            +EncodingUtil.urlEncode(+input.message, 'UTF-8')
            +'&To='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode('+91'+input.phone, 'UTF-8');
        httpReq.setBody(body);
            HttpResponse response = (new Http() ).send(httpReq); 
        system.debug('response' +response.getBody() );
        if(response.getStatusCode() == 200){
            
        }else{
            
        }
    }
    public class InputWrapper{
        @InvocableVariable(label=' Message' required=false)
        public string message;
        @InvocableVariable(label='Saalesforce user contact No' required=false)
        public string phone; 
        @InvocableVariable(label='Twilio contact No' required=false)
        public string twilioPhone;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please check out [help/on-topic] and [ask] to learn about the format of our community. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom metadata with appropriate fields to store the details which you want
2. Query the custom metadata records in your class and populate the details in a some variable/map
3. Use the variable/Map in place of the custom label

complete step 1 (I am assuming you'll 2 fields on the metadata accountSID, twilio_phone)

For step 2 :

create a new method like below :

```
    private Map<String,String> getMetadataConfig(){
    
    Map<String, String> configMap = new Map<String, String>();
    
    List<Your_Custom_metadata__mdt> configs = [Select id, accountSID__c, twilio_phone__c from Your_Custom_metadata__mdt];
    
    //Make this bulkified
    configMap.put('sid', configs[0].accountSID__c);
    configMap.put('phone', configs[0].twilio_phone__c);
    return configMap;}

private static void sendSMS(InputWrapper input){
    Map<String, String> configMap = getMetadataConfig();
    HttpRequest httpReq = new HttpRequest();        
    httpReq.setEndpoint('callout:Twilio'+'/2010-04-01/Accounts/'+configMap.get('sid')+'/Messages.json');
    //httpReq.setHeader('Authorization', authoraizationHeader);
    httpReq.setMethod('POST');
    httpReq.setHeader('Content-Type', '"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"');
    String body = 'From='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(configMap.get('phone'), 'UTF-8')+'&Body='
        +EncodingUtil.urlEncode(+input.message, 'UTF-8')
        +'&To='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode('+91'+input.phone, 'UTF-8');
    httpReq.setBody(body);
        HttpResponse response = (new Http() ).send(httpReq); 
    system.debug('response' +response.getBody() );
    if(response.getStatusCode() == 200){
        
    }else{
        
    }
}
```